# Managing members in ArcGIS Online - Multiple member content transfer then delete

Tags: arcgis-online, administration

I would like to delete about 15+ members in our organization's ArcGIS Online account. I know I can transfer the content of each member to another member's account and then delete the former. I would like to know if their is a way to do this for multiple members at one time?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing this individually for each member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the [ArcGIS REST API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Quick_reference/02r3000000m3000000/).  First [move your data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Move_Items/02r30000008v000000/) and then [delete your users](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Delete_User/02r3000000mw000000/).  I'd also recommend taking a look the [ArcRest](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST) python package or ESRI's supported [portalpy](https://github.com/Esri/portalpy) you can use either to login and generate tokens easily. among many other useful admin functions.